# Untap button after sending a POST request

Tags: button, swiftui, rest

I'm currently working with POST requests and I'm trying to POST data to postman. The data is being sent, but after I press the "send" button, [it won't untap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOOUB.png). What could be the reason behind it? This is my button view:

```
        Button(action: {
                loginManager.firstName = addFirstName
                loginManager.lastName = addLastName
                loginManager.emailAddress = addEmail
                loginManager.phoneNumber = addPhoneNumber
                loginManager.addNewUser()
        }) {
            ZStack {
            Text("Send")
            }
        }
```

And this is the section of the addNewUser function that sends the data to postman:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
     
            // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
            }
    }
    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()
```

Is there something that I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason is blocked main queue by `semaphore.wait()`. You need to return/assign data asynchronously from callback.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. You mean to say that I still have to assign the values of my variables asynchronously? How would I go about doing that?